# hide a field from a TableRow programatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a TableLayout and i fill it programmatically, but I want that when I click on the row change one value on the whole table, here is my code:

```
            for (int i = 0 ; i < adress ; i++) {
              String adress = notepad.get(i).getadress();
              String Phone = notepad.get(i).getphone();

            View noteView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivityContext()).inflate(R.layout.notepad_table, note_pad_table_Layout, false);

            TextView adressTextView = (TextView) quoteView.findViewById(R.id.note_pad_adress);
            TextView phoneTextView = (TextView) quoteView.findViewById(R.id.note_pad_phone);

            adressTextView.setText(adress);
            phoneTextView.setText(Phone);

        adressTextView.setOnClickListener(new HideClickListener());

       note_pad_table_Layout.addView(noteView);
    }
```

and this is my layout:

```
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_pad_adress"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/note_pad_phone"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"/>
<TableRow/>
```

Comment: What is your reason for using `TableLayout` instead of `ListView`?

Comment: I also edited your code. You can click on the time stamp above my avatar to see the change history. Note the empty line before the first line of code and the extra spaces before some lines in your layout code.

Comment: Thanks for editing it, Im kind of new so it was really hard to do so, i am using a table layout because Im a beginner, and i find it easier that way if you can show me how to do the same think with a ListView that could be helpful

Comment: There are many online tutorials about `ListView`. After you go over some of these, please come back with any questions you have.

Comment: Also, when posting or editing a question or answer, there is a help button in the tool bar above the text area. Reading this will help you learn about your formatting options here. To help with more commonly used formatting options, there are buttons in the toolbar.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I did see the help button yet is not as clear for people like me that we are just starting, thanks